# Docker Compose with React, Angular and Python server

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, docker-compose

I have a system that I need to dockerize which has two FE, one in React and another in Angular.
The BE is a Python server.

I have created 4 Dockerfiles:

```
# Angular
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g bower
RUN npm install -g gulp
RUN npm install gulp-cli
RUN npm install gulp --save-dev
RUN bower install
RUN npm rebuild node-sass
EXPOSE 3000

#Python Server
FROM python:2
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /src
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN pip install mysqlclient
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
EXPOSE 8000

# React Dockerfile from first directory
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install
RUN npm start &
EXPOSE 3002

# React Dockerfile from second directory
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install
RUN npm start &
EXPOSE 3001
```

The code is in Python 2.7.

This is the Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    server:
        image: python:2
        build:
            context: ./insurance_site/
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/insurance_site
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        restart: on-failure
        container_name: server
    angular:
        image: ubuntu:20.04
        build:
            context: ./fuse/
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/fuse
        command:
            - npm install gulp &
            - gulp serve watch
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        restart: on-failure
        container_name: angular
    react:
        image: ubuntu:20.04
        build:
            context: ./react/
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/react
        #command: npm start
        ports:
            - 3001:3001
        depends_on:
            - angular
        restart: on-failure
        container_name: react            
    admin:
        image: ubuntu:20.04
        build:
            context: ./admin-tools/
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/admin-tools
        restart: on-failure
        container_name: admin               
        #command: npm start
        ports:
            - 3002:3002
        depends_on:
            - angular
```

When running it in this order, I get the error:
npm ERR! missing script: start

If I change the order for the angular to be first and then the server I get this error:
Local gulp not found in /app
Try running: npm install gulp

Which I know is installed and running successfully.

If I change it to the React first and then server and Angular I get this:
npm ERR! missing script: start

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two substantial errors in this `docker-compose.yml` file.

A Docker image only runs one command.  In many contexts you can express that in two ways, either as a simple string or as an explicit list of words.  The `angular` image runs a *single* `command:`.  It has two words, and each word includes embedded spaces and punctuation; it is like running in your shell `'npm install gulp &' 'gulp serve watch'`, which will produce a similar error.

If a Compose service has both `image:` and `build:`, then when you `docker-compose build` the application, it first builds the image according to `build:`, then saves it locally under the name `image:`.  What that means in your case is that the image named `ubuntu:20.04` is a mash-mash of all three of your applications built together.

---

What would make this setup actually work?  You probably don't need to be actively developing all three of these applications at the same time.  Front-end applications also don't really participate in the container ecosystem in many interesting ways; since they ultimately run in the browser and not a container, they can't use Docker networking to reach other containers, for example.  You can use `docker-compose up` to launch this stack, and then use Node on the host to develop, debug, and unit-test an individual part of the application.

The individual images just need to `COPY` the application code in and `RUN npm install`:

```sh
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json .
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm start
```

In the `docker-compose.yml` file you can remove most of the options.  You don't need to repeat the Dockerfile `FROM` or `CMD` lines, and since the code is in the image already you don't need `volumes:`.  You should be able to reduce the complete `docker-compose.yml` to:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  server:
    build: ./insurance_site
    ports: [8000:8000]
    restart: on-failure
  angular:
    build: ./fuse
    ports: [3000:3000]
    restart: on-failure
  react:
    build: ./react
    ports: [3001:3000]
    restart: on-failure
  admin:
    build: ./admin-tools
    ports: [3002:3000]
    restart: on-failure
```

You will need to `docker rm python:2 ubuntu:20.04` to clean up your incorrectly-modified local images.  Docker will pull them again from Docker Hub when it goes to build the application images.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
This actually what I did and it solved the issue.